# Opening a file using java.awt.Desktop while redirecting it's stderr?

Tags: java, awt, desktop, stderr

I can use `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop.open(someFile)` to open a file with the system default application.  However, if that application has any output, it will show in the console. Since I'm making a command line utility, this is ugly/unnecessary. Is there any way to redirect it's standard error stream?

If this cannot be done, what about finding the path to the executable which `Desktop` would use to open the file? After gathering that information, it would be simple enough to use a `Process`/`ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: I'm no pro at this, but I *think* that this may be an inherent problem with using Desktop to start a new process.

Comment: Actually you don't need the path to the executable if you use `ProcessBuilder`. If you're working on Windows you can use `new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c", filepath).start()` and then `cmd.exe` will open the file with the default program. I'm not sure on Linux but I think if you only use `new ProcessBuilder(filePath).start()` it will work (I can't test it right now).

Comment: @dic19 The second suggestion throws an `IOException` (permission denied). The files aren't executable. I'll have to take your word for the Windows solution, because I don't necessarily want to reboot. Even if it does work, it won't help people on other platforms.

Comment: Please trust me that it works on Windows I already tested it. I googled (is it actually a word?) a little for the same behaviour on Linux. Try `new ProcessBuilder("xdg-open", filePath).start()`. See [Xdg-open](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open). Of course I agree it still a limited/non-flexible solution. Xdg-open is present by default in many Linux distributions.

Comment: I tested `new ProcessBuilder("xdg-open", filePath).start()` on Linux Mint and it worked. But once again it's an ugly/limited workaround to this matter.

Comment: @dic19 At this point the best course of action is probably to use your cmd/xdg-open solutions. You can submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle it's not necessary know the path to the default program to open a file if you will use `ProcessBuilder`. You can delegate this task to the Operating System through `cmd.exe` on Windows and `xdg-open` on Linux (see [Xdg-open](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open)) as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    String filePath = args[0];        
    String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");
    try{
        if(operatingSystem.toLowerCase().contains("windows")){
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe","/c",filePath);                
            Process p = pb.start();                

        } else if (operatingSystem.toLowerCase().contains("linux")){                
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("xdg-open",filePath);
            Process p = pb.start();

        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Not supported for %1$1s", operatingSystem));
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

*Note:* I'm not using `ProcessBuilder#redirectError` method because it's just an example.

*Disclaimer:* as I said in my comments it is an ugly/limited workaround to this matter, but it works.

Comment: You're wellcome! Great news about Mac distros, you can use the same command for that OS :)